# Cannot configure css modules to work with vue-loader

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, css-modules, vue-loader

CSS modules are not working on my fresh vue project, installed via vue-cli3.
The are two config examples in the docs. One of them is ignored by my application, second shows errors upon build

I use following component to test configs:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
      The red text here
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>

<style module>
  .hello {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

1. First doc example:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#referencing-assets

> You can use CSS Modules in *.vue files out of the box with `<style module>`.

My `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            css: {
                localIdentName: '[name]-[hash]',
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The text is still black

2. Second doc example (The first code snippet in the link below):

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html

My `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                // enable CSS Modules
                                modules: true,
                                // customize generated class names
                                localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:8]'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Gives error when I do `npm run serve`:

```
Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(5:1) Unknown word

  3 | // load the styles
  4 | var content = require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--13-1!../../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&module=true&lang=css&");
> 5 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
    | ^
  6 | if(content.locals) module.exports = content.locals;
  7 | // add the styles to the DOM
```

I found quite a lot of issues on github regarding last error, but no answer

Please help me to understand, what I do wrong.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue at the moment, please keep us updated!

Comment: still no answers?

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt was almost ok, just pass the module flag:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        module: true, // here is the config
        css: {
          localIdentName: '[name]-[hash]',
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hot reloading doesn't always work with css modules, so refresh often.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have following error with your config ```Invalid options in vue.config.js: child "css" fails because [child "loaderOptions" fails because ["module" is not allowed]]```

Comment: I was wrong. It should work without this flag. Make sure you use latest vue-cli service.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const options = {
      sourceMap: false,
      importLoaders: 2,
      modules: {
        localIdentName: '[name]______[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
        auto: () => true,
      },
    };

    config.module.rule('css').oneOf('vue-modules').use('css-loader').options(options);
    config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('vue-modules').use('css-loader').options(options);
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('vue-modules').use('css-loader').options(options);
    config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('vue-modules').use('css-loader').options(options);
    config.module.rule('less').oneOf('vue-modules').use('css-loader').options(options);
    config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('vue-modules').use('css-loader').options(options);
  },
};
```